# Turbine AMQP does not receive Hystrix stream

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud, netflix, hystrix, turbine

I had a Turbine and Hystrix setup working, but decided to change it over to Turbine AMQP so I could aggregate multiple services into one stream/dashboard.

I have set up a Turbine AMQP server running on localhost:8989, but it doesn't appear to be getting Hystrix data from the client service.  When I hit the Turbine server's IP in my browser, I see `data: {"type":"Ping"}` repeatedly, even while I am polling the URL of the Hystrix.  If I attempt to show the Turbine AMQP stream in the Hystrix Dashboard, I get: `Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream.`

I have a default install of RabbitMQ running on port 5672.

My client service using Hystrix-AMQP has a application.yml file that looks like so:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: policy-service
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    addresses: ${vcap.services.${PREFIX:}rabbitmq.credentials.uri:amqp://${RABBITMQ_HOST:localhost}:${RABBITMQ_PORT:5672}}
```

The tail end of the startup log looks like this:

```
2015-09-14 16:31:13.030  INFO 52844 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 30
2015-09-14 16:31:13.047  INFO 52844 --- [           main] c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration : Registering application policy-service with eureka with status UP
2015-09-14 16:31:13.194  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2015-09-14 16:31:13.195  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'policy-service:8088.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-09-14 16:31:13.195  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2015-09-14 16:31:13.195  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {filter} as a subscriber to the 'cloudBusOutboundFlow.channel#0' channel
2015-09-14 16:31:13.195  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'policy-    service:8088.cloudBusOutboundFlow.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-09-14 16:31:13.195  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
2015-09-14 16:31:13.195  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {filter} as a subscriber to the 'cloudBusInboundChannel' channel
2015-09-14 16:31:13.195  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'policy-service:8088.cloudBusInboundChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-09-14 16:31:13.196  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1
2015-09-14 16:31:13.196  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {message-handler} as a subscriber to the 'cloudBusInboundFlow.channel#0' channel
2015-09-14 16:31:13.196  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'policy-service:8088.cloudBusInboundFlow.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-09-14 16:31:13.196  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2
2015-09-14 16:31:13.196  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter} as a subscriber to the 'cloudBusWiretapChannel' channel
2015-09-14 16:31:13.196  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'policy-service:8088.cloudBusWiretapChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-09-14 16:31:13.197  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#3
2015-09-14 16:31:13.197  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {amqp:outbound-channel-adapter} as a subscriber to the 'cloudBusOutboundChannel' channel
2015-09-14 16:31:13.197  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'policy-service:8088.cloudBusOutboundChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-09-14 16:31:13.197  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#4
2015-09-14 16:31:13.198  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {bridge} as a subscriber to the 'cloudBusAmqpInboundFlow.channel#0' channel
2015-09-14 16:31:13.198  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'policy-service:8088.cloudBusAmqpInboundFlow.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-09-14 16:31:13.198  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#5
2015-09-14 16:31:13.198  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {amqp:outbound-channel-adapter} as a subscriber to the 'hystrixStream' channel
2015-09-14 16:31:13.199  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'policy-service:8088.hystrixStream' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-09-14 16:31:13.199  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#6
2015-09-14 16:31:13.219  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 1073741823
2015-09-14 16:31:13.219  INFO 52844 --- [           main] ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer : started org.springframework.integration.event.inbound.ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer#0
2015-09-14 16:31:13.555  INFO 52844 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Auto-declaring a non-durable, auto-delete, or exclusive Queue (4640c1c8-ff8f-45d7-8426-19d1b7a4cdb0) durable:false, auto-delete:true, exclusive:true. It will be redeclared if the broker stops and is restarted while the connection factory is alive, but all messages will be lost.
2015-09-14 16:31:13.572  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.i.a.i.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter      : started org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter#0
2015-09-14 16:31:13.573  INFO 52844 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2015-09-14 16:31:13.576  INFO 52844 --- [           main] c.n.h.c.m.e.HystrixMetricsPoller         : Starting HystrixMetricsPoller
2015-09-14 16:31:13.609  INFO 52844 --- [           main] ration$HystrixMetricsPollerConfiguration : Starting poller
2015-09-14 16:31:13.803  INFO 52844 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8088 (http)
2015-09-14 16:31:13.805  INFO 52844 --- [           main] com.ml.springboot.PolicyService     : Started PolicyService in 22.544 seconds (JVM running for 23.564)
```

So it looks like PolicyService successfully connects to the message broker.

The Turbine AMQP server's end of log:

```
2015-09-14 16:58:05.887  INFO 51944 --- [           main] i.reactivex.netty.server.AbstractServer  : Rx server started at port: 8989
2015-09-14 16:58:05.991  INFO 51944 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2015-09-14 16:58:05.991  INFO 51944 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'bootstrap:-1.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-09-14 16:58:05.991  INFO 51944 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2015-09-14 16:58:05.991  INFO 51944 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {bridge} as a subscriber to the 'hystrixStreamAggregatorInboundFlow.channel#0' channel
2015-09-14 16:58:05.991  INFO 51944 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'bootstrap:-1.hystrixStreamAggregatorInboundFlow.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-09-14 16:58:05.991  INFO 51944 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
2015-09-14 16:58:05.991  INFO 51944 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 1073741823
2015-09-14 16:58:06.238  INFO 51944 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Auto-declaring a non-durable, auto-delete, or exclusive Queue (spring.cloud.hystrix.stream) durable:false, auto-delete:false, exclusive:false. It will be redeclared if the broker stops and is restarted while the connection factory is alive, but all messages will be lost.
2015-09-14 16:58:06.289  INFO 51944 --- [           main] o.s.i.a.i.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter      : started org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter#0
2015-09-14 16:58:06.290  INFO 51944 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2015-09-14 16:58:06.434  INFO 51944 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): -1 (http)
```

Any ideas why the Turbine AMQP server is not receiving communication from the Hystrix AMQP client?

EDIT: Turbine-AMQP main looks like:

```
package com.turbine.amqp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.turbine.amqp.EnableTurbineAmqp;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTurbineAmqp
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class TurbineAmqpApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TurbineAmqpApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here's its application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8989
spring:
  rabbitmq:
addresses: ${vcap.services.${PREFIX:}rabbitmq.credentials.uri:amqp://${RABBITMQ_HOST:localhost}:${RABBITMQ_PORT:5672}}
```

Hitting `http://localhost:8989/turbine.stream` produces a repeating stream of `data: {"type":"Ping"}`

and shows this in console:

```
2015-09-15 08:54:37.960  INFO 83480 --- [o-eventloop-3-1] o.s.c.n.t.amqp.TurbineAmqpConfiguration  : SSE Request Received
2015-09-15 08:54:38.025  INFO 83480 --- [o-eventloop-3-1] o.s.c.n.t.amqp.TurbineAmqpConfiguration  : Starting aggregation
```

EDIT: The below exception is thrown when I *stop* listening to the turbine stream, not when I try to listen with the dashboard.

```
2015-09-15 08:56:47.934  INFO 83480 --- [o-eventloop-3-3] o.s.c.n.t.amqp.TurbineAmqpConfiguration  : SSE Request Received
2015-09-15 08:56:47.946  WARN 83480 --- [o-eventloop-3-3] io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline  : An exception was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: rx.Observable.collect(Lrx/functions/Func0;Lrx/functions/Action2;)Lrx/Observable;
    at com.netflix.turbine.aggregator.StreamAggregator.lambda$null$36(StreamAggregator.java:89)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMulticastSelector.call(OnSubscribeMulticastSelector.java:60)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMulticastSelector.call(OnSubscribeMulticastSelector.java:40)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8591)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.handleNewSource(OperatorMerge.java:190)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:160)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:96)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorGroupBy$GroupBySubscriber.onNext(OperatorGroupBy.java:173)
    at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.onNext(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:224)
    at rx.subjects.PublishSubject.onNext(PublishSubject.java:101)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.turbine.amqp.Aggregator.handle(Aggregator.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:102)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:342)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:164)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:276)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:71)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:239)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:248)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:119)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:239)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$400(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$1.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:756)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:167)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1241)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:660)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:989)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1103)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: GroupedObservable.class
    at rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(OnErrorThrowable.java:98)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:56)
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

My dependencies for turbine-amqp are as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-turbine-amqp:1.0.3.RELEASE')
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.2.5.RELEASE'

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") 
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports { 
         mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-parent:1.0.2.RELEASE'
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Did you exercise the circuit breaker? What does the config & main of turbine-amqp app look like? Can you hit <turbine-amqp app>/turbine.stream? What url did you put in the hystrix dashboard? I don't have enough details.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this, I've added the details you asked for, but I'm not sure what you mean by exercising the circuit breaker.

Comment: Somewhere in the client app, you've created a hystrix command (a circuit breaker). If that code path hasn't been reached, all you get are pings.

Comment: Oh! Yes, I am hitting the HystrixCommand multiple times and still just seeing pings come across on `http://localhost:8989/turbine.stream`

Comment: I am able to see that messages are being passed in the Rabbit MQ management console.

Answer (score 1):

It is so hard to find a solution.

Using Spring cloud 2.1.4.RELEASE I faced with similar problem.

The main cause is the incompatibility [exchanges] name in rabbitMQ between:
spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-stream and spring-cloud-starter-netflix-turbine-stream.

So solve it:
See the name created exchange name when you start the service componente {the same that declare hystrix-stream}

on the componente that declare {turbine-stream}
update the property

turbine.stream.destination=

in my case
turbine.stream.destination=hystrixStreamOutput

Comment: Can you give a full example?

Comment: @Marcelus - 'turbine.stream.destination' is an unknown property. What extra dependency you added in pom.xml?

Comment: @Marcelus - Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59738969/unable-to-connect-to-command-metric-stream-in-hystrix-dashboard-issue ?

Comment: Thank you, I've struggling with `spring.cloud.version` things

Answer (score 0):

I faced with similar problem and I find a solution.

My Spring Cloud version is 2.1.0.RELEASE

The solution:

1. add property

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.turbineStreamInput.destination: hystrixStreamOutput
turbine.stream.enabled: false
```

2. add auto configuration

```java
@EnableBinding(TurbineStreamClient.class)
public class TurbineStreamAutoConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private BindingServiceProperties bindings;

    @Autowired
    private TurbineStreamProperties properties;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        BindingProperties inputBinding = this.bindings.getBindings()
                .get(TurbineStreamClient.INPUT);
        if (inputBinding == null) {
            this.bindings.getBindings().put(TurbineStreamClient.INPUT,
                    new BindingProperties());
        }
        BindingProperties input = this.bindings.getBindings()
                .get(TurbineStreamClient.INPUT);
        if (input.getDestination() == null) {
            input.setDestination(this.properties.getDestination());
        }
        if (input.getContentType() == null) {
            input.setContentType(this.properties.getContentType());
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public HystrixStreamAggregator hystrixStreamAggregator(ObjectMapper mapper,
            PublishSubject<Map<String, Object>> publisher) {
        return new HystrixStreamAggregator(mapper, publisher);
    }

}
```