# Netflix Turbine - Server port automatically update to -1

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud, turbine, spring-cloud-netflix

It seems a simple question, but I'm racking my brain with this:
I have a Netflix Turbine being configured to run on a port 8989, but suddenly this log appears when starting this module:

```
INFO 17007 --- [main] c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration : Updating port to -1
```

These are all the configs / code / logs that I suppose to be useful in order to someone give me a hint:

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8989

management:
  port: 8990
```

**Main class:**

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.turbine.amqp.EnableTurbineAmqp;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTurbineAmqp
@EnableEurekaClient
public class TurbineApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(TurbineApplication.class).run(args);
    }
}
```

Dependencies:
[web, undertow, turbine-amqp, eureka and test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43pnY.png)

**Logs:**

```
2016-05-04 22:35:57.956  INFO 17007 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1fde5d22: startup date [Wed May 04 22:35:57 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-05-04 22:35:58.196  INFO 17007 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-05-04 22:35:58.215  INFO 17007 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$39bb4bdf] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.3.RELEASE)

2016-05-04 22:35:58.667  INFO 17007 --- [           main] c.s.n.o.m.TurbineApplication             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-05-04 22:35:58.689  INFO 17007 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@64040287: startup date [Wed May 04 22:35:58 CEST 2016]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1fde5d22
2016-05-04 22:35:59.464  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2016-05-04 22:35:59.529  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.config.PropertiesFactoryBean     : Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/home/fernando/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]
2016-05-04 22:35:59.533  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.i.config.IntegrationRegistrar        : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2016-05-04 22:35:59.781  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=ff867fd3-adba-376f-92d4-71d9d667c9a8
2016-05-04 22:35:59.799  INFO 17007 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2016-05-04 22:35:59.805  INFO 17007 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
2016-05-04 22:35:59.828  INFO 17007 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-05-04 22:35:59.839  INFO 17007 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8f4974f0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-05-04 22:35:59.925  INFO 17007 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$39bb4bdf] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-05-04 22:36:00.371  WARN 17007 --- [           main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026009: XNIO worker was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default worker will be used
2016-05-04 22:36:00.416  INFO 17007 --- [           main] org.xnio                                 : XNIO version 3.3.4.Final
2016-05-04 22:36:00.440  INFO 17007 --- [           main] org.xnio.nio                             : XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.4.Final
2016-05-04 22:36:00.643  WARN 17007 --- [           main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026010: Buffer pool was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default pool will be used
2016-05-04 22:36:00.679  INFO 17007 --- [           main] io.undertow.servlet                      : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-05-04 22:36:00.680  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1991 ms
2016-05-04 22:36:01.165  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-05-04 22:36:01.172  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-05-04 22:36:01.174  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-05-04 22:36:01.174  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-05-04 22:36:01.174  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-05-04 22:36:02.462  INFO 17007 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@64040287: startup date [Wed May 04 22:35:58 CEST 2016]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1fde5d22
2016-05-04 22:36:02.650  INFO 17007 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-05-04 22:36:02.652  INFO 17007 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-05-04 22:36:02.770  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-05-04 22:36:02.770  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-05-04 22:36:02.902  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-05-04 22:36:03.543  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.config.PropertiesFactoryBean     : Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/home/fernando/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]
2016-05-04 22:36:03.585  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService  'taskScheduler'
2016-05-04 22:36:03.705  WARN 17007 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2016-05-04 22:36:03.706  INFO 17007 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2016-05-04 22:36:03.718  WARN 17007 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2016-05-04 22:36:03.718  INFO 17007 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2016-05-04 22:36:04.179  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-05-04 22:36:04.190  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'refreshScope' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-05-04 22:36:04.190  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'environmentManager' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-05-04 22:36:04.192  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'configurationPropertiesRebinder' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-05-04 22:36:04.195  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'environmentManager': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager]
2016-05-04 22:36:04.210  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'refreshScope': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh:name=refreshScope,type=RefreshScope]
2016-05-04 22:36:04.221  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinder': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties:name=configurationPropertiesRebinder,context=64040287,type=ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder]
2016-05-04 22:36:04.525  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase -2147483648
2016-05-04 22:36:04.526  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {service-activator:hystrixStreamAggregator.handle.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'hystrixStreamAggregator' channel
2016-05-04 22:36:04.526  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'turbine:-1.hystrixStreamAggregator' has 1 subscriber(s).
2016-05-04 22:36:04.526  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started hystrixStreamAggregator.handle.serviceActivator
2016-05-04 22:36:04.526  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase -2147482648
2016-05-04 22:36:04.526  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2016-05-04 22:36:04.599  INFO 17007 --- [           main] i.reactivex.netty.server.AbstractServer  : Rx server started at port: 8989
2016-05-04 22:36:04.600  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2016-05-04 22:36:04.600  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'turbine:-1.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2016-05-04 22:36:04.600  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2016-05-04 22:36:04.600  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {bridge} as a subscriber to the 'hystrixStreamAggregatorInboundFlow.channel#0' channel
2016-05-04 22:36:04.600  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'turbine:-1.hystrixStreamAggregatorInboundFlow.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2016-05-04 22:36:04.600  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
2016-05-04 22:36:04.600  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 1073741823
2016-05-04 22:36:04.909  INFO 17007 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: SimpleConnection@6eed8333 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/]
2016-05-04 22:36:04.912  INFO 17007 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Auto-declaring a non-durable, auto-delete, or exclusive Queue (spring.cloud.hystrix.stream) durable:false, auto-delete:false, exclusive:false. It will be redeclared if the broker stops and is restarted while the connection factory is alive, but all messages will be lost.
2016-05-04 22:36:04.956  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.i.a.i.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter      : started org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter#0
2016-05-04 22:36:04.956  INFO 17007 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2016-05-04 22:36:04.972  INFO 17007 --- [           main] c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration : Updating port to -1
2016-05-04 22:36:04.977  INFO 17007 --- [           main] c.s.n.o.m.TurbineApplication             : Started TurbineApplication in 7.689 seconds (JVM running for 8.495)
```

Sorry if the question is basic, I've found some similar issues (for instance, [Turbine AMQP does not receive Hystrix stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573966/turbine-amqp-does-not-receive-hystrix-stream)), however, none of them is equal to my problem.

P.S.: I have a Rabbit running on default port, monitor dashboard, hystrix commands and everything else.

Could anyone, please, give me a clue if I'm missing something and why this server port configuration is being "overwritten" by *-1* value?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the server.port in turbine project application.yml and replace it with

```
turbine:
  amqp:
    port: 8989
```